# I want to search something in a file knowing only few chars

Tags: shell-script

I have a problem. I'm doing a script which one will get as a parameter $1 some charters. I have file "drinks.txt" where there have written few lines like this:

```
Cocacola
juice
CocaPepsi
```

I'm going to pass as a parameter "co" for example, and this should return me Cocacola and CocaPepsi. I'm failing with IF condition. Here is my code:

```
searchingParameter=$1
for drink in `cat drinks.txt`;do
   if [ "$drink" == "$1*" ]; then
      echo "$drink"
   fi
done
```

So this should print every drink that found with $1 plus *.
What's the correct way to do the IF for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this with a shell loop is awkward and error prone.  If your `drinks.txt` file contains a `*` on a line by itself (or surrounded by spaces), it would expand to the names of the files in the current directory, for example.

Instead, just use `grep`:

```
grep -iF 'co' drinks.txt
```

Here, we use `grep` with `-i` to do a case-insensitive match.  The `-F` option means that `grep` should use the pattern as a *string* rather than as a regular expression (this does not matter here, but *would* matter if your pattern contained characters like `*` or `.` or other special regular expression symbols).

The command would return each complete line that contained the string `co`, `Co`, `cO` or `CO`.

As part of a script:

```
#!/bin/sh

grep -iF -e "$1" drinks.txt
```

I'm using `-e` here to say "the next argument is a pattern".  If I didn't do that and `$1` started with a dash, it would be taken as an option to `grep`.

To force a match at the start of a word, you would use

```
grep -i -e '\b'"$1" drinks.txt
```

or

```
grep -i -e '\<'"$1" drinks.txt
```

Where `\b` and `\<` both would match at a word boundary.   Note that we had to remove the `-F` option here, because our pattern is now a regular expression.  This also means that any regular expression characters in `$1` will be special.

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda!

grep -i -e '\<'"$1" drinks.txt  helped me to solve the issue.

Thanks again

Comment: `\b` or `\<` or `[[:<:]]` are not standard. Most portable of the three probably `\<` (and even then, there are variations as to what constitutes a _word_ character). POSIXly,  you can do `grep -i "^\(.*[^[:alnum:]_]\)\{0,1\}$1"`